# Printing a list of Selenium Webdriver Elements returns serial number-like information; how can I make sense of this?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to find all the iframes on a particular page, so I can use Selenium Webdriver to navigate in and out of the iframes.

I used a query like

```
print(browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

and the command line returned:

```
 C:\Python27\...path>file_name.py[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="04088140-f-4b7d-849b-68bed36bc5c2", element="b78df9a9-b80f-4493-ac9f-b116d95ef5a6")>]
```

My question is: what does the form `element="b78df9a9-b80f-4493-ac9f-b116d95ef5a6"` refer to? I understand it's the webdriver element, but how can one interpret the number itself? Furthermore, if I am to print out a list of the iframes by, say, `id`, how could I go about doing so?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `id` of each `iframe` element instead of its `UUID`, you can do something like:

```
frames = [frame.get_attribute('id') for frame in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')]
```

Note, that not every `iframe` could have an `id` attribute (`iframe` without `id` will be represent with `None` value in `frames` list)

Comment: Thanks. It was the `get_attribute` element I was looking for, in addition to the `UUID` term. I've never quite heard of that label before.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the id that is assigned to the element ( that you gave name while creating it) use other methods like element_by_id or elements_by_class etc to get something specific.